# Asterisk, display queue name or called number on the phone

Tags: asterisk, queue

Our Asterisk server will soon receive SIP calls on multiple numbers, so we need to know which number has been dialed to correctly answer on the phone : "Hello, this is Company-A" or "Hello, this is Company-B".

We are a bunch of people answering, so the dialplan is organized with multiple queues : one per incoming number, based on the `${EXTEN}` variable.

Now, the last step is to display on the phone (Yealink ones) ideally the queue name, or if not possible the incoming dialed number.

How can I achieve this in the dialplan ?

Comment: Can you tell us: which SIP provider are you using? The dialed number is usually part of SIP headers, we'll need to figure out how your provider deals with this, ... In some cases, you might have to configure one SIP trunk per DID.

Comment: Sunrise (Switzerland) is the SIP provider. The dialed number is known within the Dialplan - it is the `${EXTEN}` variable - but how to modify what appears on the display of the phones of the queue when they ring ?

Comment: my mistake. See: https://www.voip-info.org/setting-callerid.